# Column-wise comparision of common element-Matlab

Tags: matrix, compare, element

How can I compare 2 matrices column wise; and find if there is any common element in corresponding column and return the column number (note: elements need not be in corresponding position)

Function:bsxfun(@eq,A,B) is NOT useful here as it compares corresponding elements in column.

Requirement: A=[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9],   B=[0 0 0;8 7 9;4 1 6] here value 4 is common in col#1 of A and B; similarly value 6,9 are common in column 3 of A&B; So return column 1 and column 3.

Can you please suggest a method; I would be grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ismember` to compare columns (or rows) as you describe. It returns a logical index of A indicating matches in B. Use `any` to reduce column wise and `find` to get the column indices.

You can use a for loop over columns or use `arrayfun`:

```
find(arrayfun(@(c) any(ismember(A(:,c), B(:,c))), 1:size(A,2)))
```

I would be interested to see if you find a neater, more succinct solution!

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, Its more efficient. My plan was to rotate each row ( 'row' number of times) and check for equality (that gives 1 or 0), and return the column number.   for c=0:2
s=circshift(B,[c 0])
d = bsxfun(@eq,s,A)
[maxValue d] = max(d,[],2)
min_count=min(d).